# Can vocal range extension be achieved by technique only? Or are exercises the key?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, falsetto

I hear all the time people talking about extending vocal range with exercises, and people talk about mixed voice... can someone clarify those questions for me  (that I believe are related to each other)?

Do vocal range exercises extend the "chest" vocal range without any use of technique, or is it practicing some technique?

Is the method of using mixed voice just a technique to extend vocal range? or not related at all?

Comment: Most likely relaxation is the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is overlap in the meaning of the terms.

**Technique** can mean:

- A specific way of using the voice. Chest voice, mixed voice, head voice, are all terms for different vocal *techniques*; ways of using the voice.
- A general term for proper/healthy use of the voice. "That singer has good technique."

**Extending one's range** can mean:

- Singing higher and lower within a particular vocal technique (such as extending the range of one's chest voice, but without moving out of chest voice).
- Extending one's overall vocal range (e.g., by developing various vocal techniques, such as mixed voice).

Thus...

- Chest voice exercises can develop one's chest voice technique and extend one's chest voice range.
- Mixed voice exercises can develop one's mixed voice technique and extend one's overall voice range.

Comment: when you say the mixed voice help extending the overall vocal range, do you mean the you can use mixed voice in places you cannot you chest  voice? or you can do transition from chest to head in a smooth way that is singale?

Comment: Mixed voice is generally used in transition from chest voice to head voice, but it also can allow for notes higher than chest voice (or lower than head voice).